# Screen Recording - NO COMPRESSION

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, script, screen-capture

I'm looking to record my screen similar to how Quicktime does it, but I need zero-compression, since I need the pixel colors to remain correct.

Basically, I need a automated series of screenshots, if that's possible - lossless PNG at half-second intervals.

Are there scripts or other tools to do this?

Comment: I use [Camtasia 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camtasia-2/id478330793?mt=12) which works great for me. I have no idea if it compresses the output at all though. I suppose you could check with them and see.

Comment: What rate of pictures is acceptable and which codecs / still image formats are acceptable to you?

Comment: You say no compression, but would lossless compression be acceptable?  I suspect it's only lossy compression you object to; is that correct?

Comment: @bmike - png, every half-second?

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you'd like [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm); it offers lossless compression.
[image]